# What happened to Lucy Stillman?

Tags: assassins-creed, assassins-creed-series

It has been a while since I've played Assassin's Creed 1, and I'm trying to refresh myself on the plot as I play the newer games.  I've come across something that's been bothering me.  I could swear there was a scene where you see that:

> Lucy Stillman's left ring finger was partially amputated, similar to Altaïr.

This was a memorable moment from the game, and caused me to draw conclusions about Lucy that are important to the plot.  I am now playing AC Brotherhood, and during certain scenes I can clearly see that:

> Lucy has all of her fingers!

Did I remember wrong, is this a glaring plot hole, or is there some plausible explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having had this question, I did some research which I thought I would share.

In AC 1 you do see this scene

> Where Lucy flashes the Assassin version of "[the shocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocker_%28hand_gesture%29)".  [image: Lucy Shows Bent Finger]

Although there is some speculation, it is commonly held that:

> Lucy is only bending her finger in this picture.  Pictures even from AC 1 clearly show that she has all of her fingers.  [image: Lucy Has Her Fingers]This makes sense since she had plenty of Templar oversight and it is a very hard trait to hide.  Also, since you later learn that the hidden blade no longer required the amputation in more modern times - it would have been a very extreme way to show loyalty (which is exactly what I thought it was - but in retrospect this makes more sense).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this wiki link](http://wikiguides.neoseeker.com/wiki/Assassin%27s%20Creed/Lucy%20Stillman):

> [...] By doing so, she allowed Desmond to acquire a better understanding of Abstergo's background information. At the end of one conversation, Lucy symbolically pulls back her left ring finger to make it appear like Altaïr's severed finger, telling a dumbfounded Desmond to "have faith." [...]

Her role and intentions (up to what you know now playing Brotherhood) inside Abstergo is pretty clear now. And even why she does that! So to answer your question, this is not a plot hole :)

Also, there is another explanation to this, but it may result in a big big spoiler for you. **DON'T READ THIS IF YOU DID NOT FINISH AC:BH**

> At the end of AC:BH, you discover that Lucy is now a Templar infiltrating the Assassins to retrieve the Apple of Eden. Templars don't remove fingers, since they didn't have hidden blade training up to that time.